# Confusion related to the time complexity of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I was going through this algorithm https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63921/print-all-nodes-from-root-to-leaves

In one of the comments it is mentioned that printing the paths from the root to leaf itself has average time complexity of O(nlogn). I am not quite sure how he came up with that. Any clarification will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what they mean:

in the best case, the tree is perfectly balanced, and it contains N nodes, where log(N)+1 is the number of levels. The tree has N/2 leaves. 
Every time we move to a lower level, we duplicate the currently accumulated path. If you assume copying an array of length k as an O(k) operation, then when we move from the second to last level to a leaf we do an O(log(N)) operation. As there are N/2 leaves, and for each we do an O(log(N)) operation, you get O(N*log(N)).

Instead of duplicating arrays, the function could pass recursively the same array, and the current level number, making sure that the path is printed only up to the level of the leaf.